# How to style a single QToolButton using qss/css

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a toolbar with multiple toolbuttons on it, I have tried to apply a style to an individual button with:

```
QToolButton#button_name
{
    border: 3px solid #FF00FF;
}
```

I thought this would have applied a pink border to just the one button which has the name "button_name" but it does nothing.

i can apply a style to all buttons on the toolbar if i take the "#button_name" off. So im wondering if there is anyway to individual set styles for a specific QToolButton

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change `objectName` of needed widget, not `QAction`. You can get this widget with `widgetForAction()` method. For example:

```
QToolBar tool;

QAction * foo = new QAction("foo",&tool);
QAction * bar = new QAction("bar",&tool);
QAction * baz = new QAction("baz",&tool);

tool.addAction(foo);
tool.addAction(bar);
tool.addAction(baz);

tool.widgetForAction(bar)->setObjectName("unique");
tool.show();

qApp->setStyleSheet("QToolButton#unique{border: 3px solid #FF00FF;}");
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Im not declaring a QToolbutton in my code though, im Declaring it is a QAction and then adding it to the toolbar, so unfortunately this doesnt work, i did try the same by setting an object name to the action but this doesnt work either